# Add new column to SQL DB with pandas without replace

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, t-sql

is it possible to add a new column to an SQL database through pandas?

I can already read/write(append/replace) the entire database, but i would like to read the data, generate new columns, then add those column to the SQL DB.
I know this can be done by replacing the entire DB, but when i'm dealing with millions of rows(on a remote server), this get's a bit unsafe, not to mention slow.
I use the following connection:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB['servername'] + ';DATABASE=' + DB['database'] + ';UID=User;PWD=psw;')
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params))
df.to_sql(name='table',con=engine, if_exists='append',index =False)
```

Is there some way through pandas, or do i have to look for some other library?
Thanks for the help

P.S.: Not sure if relevant, the DB is a T-SQL (Microsoft) DB.

Comment: If it is possible, I wouldn't recommend it. It sounds like you want something like alembic but I'm not familiar with your DB. Pandas is an analytics tool, it seems like a dodgy recipe to try have it messing with schema

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, i'll have to see what other options i have.

Comment: I'll definitely have to caveat that with it just being my opinion :) I wouldn't put it past pandas that it could be possible, but it's definitely not specialised in this kinda thing and I'd be concerned about data loss if there's an issue